# I am unable to ndk-build

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
aison@jaison-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/pjproject-2.2.1/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/android$ ndk-build -fexceptions
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 15 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:pjsua: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lpjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjsip-ua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjsip-simple-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjsip-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjmedia-codec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjmedia-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjmedia-videodev-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjmedia-audiodev-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjmedia-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjnath-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpjlib-util-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lsrtp-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lresample-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lgsmcodec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lspeex-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lilbccodec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lg7221codec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lpj-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi -lgnustl_static -lgcc    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
make: exceptions: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `exceptions'.  Stop.
```

I am getting that error while doing `ndk-build` in Ubuntu.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ndk-build APP_CPPFLAGS=-fexceptions`, or better set this flag in file **Application.mk**.